# Connecting to HP ScanJet 4500 FN 1 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, scanner

I recently posted a question on the HP community support forum ([see this](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Scanning-Faxing-and-Copying/Network-connection-to-HP-ScanJet-4500-FN-1-network-scanner/m-p/7240027#M213809)), but past experience suggests I might get a better response here :-).

In short, I bought a new HP ScanJet Pro fn 1 a couple of years ago but I could only ever get it working via USB, and I'm now trying (unsuccessfully) to get it working as a network scanner with a brand new Windows 10 laptop. I've installed all of the latest HP software (v41.1.2220) and flashed the firmware on the scanner to the latest version (v7.128), and I can successfully ping the scanner by IP and hostname, and I can also browse the scanner's web-based admin interface without issue so the scanner *seems* to be running ok.

However, when I try to connect the scanner in the HP setup software it fails to find it by discovery or by specific IP address / hostname:

[image: HP ScanJet Pro 4500 fn 1 Setup Wizard]

As an investigation step I've installed WireShark on my laptop and found that when I click "Search" in the dialog above it sends a HTTP request to the scanner as follows:

```
POST /StableWSDiscoveryEndpoint/schemas-xmlsoap-org_ws_2005_04_discovery HTTP/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/soap+xml
User-Agent: WSDAPI
Content-Length: 520
Host: 192.168.1.65

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsa:To>urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</wsa:To> 
    <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:b05117ac-9988-4ec8-a22a-2be3b5b781f4</wsa:MessageID>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <wsd:Probe/>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and the scanner returns a HTTP 500:

```
Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 62
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: no-store
Connection: keep-alive

Error 500: Internal Server Error
read data...(): happen error!
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong, or whether this is a known issue with the ScanJet 4500 (or HP scanners in general)? And if so, is there a workaround to get network scanning working?

Thanks,

Mike

**Update - HP Print and Scan Doctor**

I've tried HP Print and Scan Doctor (v5.2.1) and it detects a another HP printer that I have on the network, but not the HP ScanJet 4500 fn 1 :-(. Running WireShark while running the utility shows a [Simple Service Discovery Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol) multi-cast request sent out to 239.255.255.250 on the local network as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery"
    xmlns:hpd="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/discovery/2006/09/19">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsa:To>urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</wsa:To>
    <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:ae1fb610-82b5-4779-be5d-7f3225f58786</wsa:MessageID>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <wsd:Probe>
      <wsd:Types>hpd:hpDevice</wsd:Types>
    </wsd:Probe>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

which gets a reply from my old HP Officejet Pro 8600, but there's zero traffic to or from the scanner.

The utility then shows a thumbnail of the printer, but nothing for the scanner, so I don't think Print and Scan Doctor can help me at this point... :-(

Comment: Have you tried HP's scan doctor?....https://support.hp.com/us-en/topic/printscandoctor

Comment: @Moab - I've added an update about HP Print and Scan Doctor - no dice I'm afraid :-(

Answer (score 0):

After a *lot* to messing about I eventually did the following, which seemed to fix the issue:

1. Re-flashed the v7.128 firmware and did a factory reset in the scanner's admin "Embedded Web Server" (EWS) admin site at https://[scanners-ip-address]/EWS/General-Restore_Factory_Settings.htm

[image: Embedded Web Server - Factory Reset]

2. Enabled WS-Discovery and WS-Scan features in "Networking -> Advanced" at https://[scanners-ip-address]/EWS/Networking-Advanced.htm

[image: Embedded Web Server - Advanced Networking Features]

I could then connect to the scanner via the network in the HP Setup wizard and, hey presto, I've got a network scanner working.

The irony is that after all that, if you use it as a network scanner you have a couple of extra dialogs to click through to start every single scan...

Firstly the desktop software gives you an instruction as follows:

[image]

and then you have to use the touchscreen panel on the scanner to navigate to "reserved jobs":

[image]

and finally tap your job to start it:

[image]

So I think I'm going to stick to the USB connection - it means more cables, but less clicks to do each scan!